# How to set uploaded photo as profile picture in facebook?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have successfully uploaded picture to facebook using Graph API v5.
But how do i make it default profile picture ? 
Following is my upload() function:

```
//Upload image
function upload($path,$token,$fb)
{
    $image = [
      'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
      'source' => $fb->fileToUpload($path), // $fb is instance
    ];

    try {
      // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
      $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $image, $token);
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

    debug_to_console($graphNode);
    echo " \n Photo ID: " . $graphNode['id'];
}
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/api

Comment: Currently Facebook graph api does not allow you to upload picture as profile picture by default.